# In Google Sheets, how do you change the sheet that the user sees?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet spreadsheet with some javascript code in it. The user(s) begin on a default sheet and the code creates and names a sheet based on the user that is accessing it.  There is a bunch of code that copies data to their sheet, formats it, resize columns, etc.  That all works fine.  All I want to do is have the focus the user sees change from the default entry sheet to the custom sheet that was created for the user.

I've tried using:

```
sheet.activate()
sheet.setCurrentCell(cell)
ss.getSheetByName(username)
```

but none of these change the active sheet on screen (UI), it just changes the focus of the script that running.

I can't use

```
ss.getSheets()[1]
```

because there may be multiple users in the spreadsheet and their personalized sheet may not necessarily be the second.

I'm not getting any errors, I'm just not getting the UI to change focus to a different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(username))` since the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setActiveSheet(Sheet)) states that 'Google Sheets UI displays the chosen sheet'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The code you provided didn't work for me, but from the documentation page, I tried their code exactly and it switched to the second sheet.  That's a start!  I think I may have an issue with my "username" variable as a sheet and that may be causing my issues.

Comment: Yup. As long as you can grab the correct sheet for `setActiveSheet()`, I believe it will do focus correctly. Glad I could help.